# Como modificar (simplificar) una estructura de datos JSON retornada por una consulta en MySQL en java?

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, spring-mvc

Tengo la siguiente estructura de datos JSON retornada de una consulta SQL, deseo simplificarla para manejar mejor los datos de lado del cliente, de forma tal que la propiedad "items" sea sobreescrita.

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "Operación realizada con éxito!",
"items": [
    {
        "idResultExercise": 1,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 7,
        "resultExercise": false
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 2,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 0,
        "resultExercise": false
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 3,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 4,
        "resultExercise": false
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 4,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 5,
        "resultExercise": true
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 5,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 1,
        "resultExercise": false
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 6,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 2,
        "resultExercise": false
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 7,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 6,
        "resultExercise": false
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 8,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 7,
        "idExercise": 3,
        "resultExercise": false
    },
    {
        "idResultExercise": 9,
        "idUser": 1,
        "idCourse": 1,
        "idLesson": 1,
        "idActivity": 6,
        "idExercise": 1,
        "resultExercise": true
    }
]
```

}

Necesito que en lugar que se manden todos los registros de la consulta, sean la propiedad "idActivity" quien sea el arreglo para sus resultados.
Es decir llegar a esta estrcutura...

```
{
"items": [{
        "exercisesIdActivity7": [{
                "idResultExercise": 1,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 7,
                "resultExercise": false
            },
            {
                "idResultExercise": 2,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 0,
                "resultExercise": false
            },
            {
                "idResultExercise": 3,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 4,
                "resultExercise": false
            },
            {
                "idResultExercise": 4,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 5,
                "resultExercise": true
            },
            {
                "idResultExercise": 5,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 1,
                "resultExercise": false
            },
            {
                "idResultExercise": 6,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 2,
                "resultExercise": false
            },
            {
                "idResultExercise": 7,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 6,
                "resultExercise": false
            },
            {
                "idResultExercise": 8,
                "idUser": 1,
                "idCourse": 1,
                "idLesson": 1,
                "idActivity": 7,
                "idExercise": 3,
                "resultExercise": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "exercisesIdActivity6": [{
            "idResultExercise": 9,
            "idUser": 1,
            "idCourse": 1,
            "idLesson": 1,
            "idActivity": 6,
            "idExercise": 1,
            "resultExercise": true
        }]
    }
]
```

}

Esto tengo de lado del servidor

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/list"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
SubmitResult listNewResultExercise(
        @RequestParam("idLesson") int idLesson,
        HttpServletRequest request
) throws IOException, Exception {

    SubmitResult result = new SubmitResult();

    ResultsExercisesJpaController jpaResultExe = new ResultsExercisesJpaController();
    try {
        List<ResultsExercises> foo = new ArrayList<ResultsExercises>();

    //Se ejecuta la consulta sql 
        foo = jpaResultExe.findLessonById(idLesson);

//Me supongo que aqui debo de modificar lo que tiene foo

        result.success = true;
        result.items = foo;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result.success = false;
        result.message = "Error: Al intentar retornar resultados " + ex.getMessage();

    }
    return result;
}
```

Metodo para hacer consulta

```
public List<ResultsExercises> findLessonById(int id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    return em.createQuery(
            "SELECT r FROM ResultsExercises r WHERE r.idLesson = :idLesson")
            .setParameter("idLesson", id)
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .getResultList();
    //SELECT r FROM ResultsExercises r WHERE r.idActivity
}
```

Codigo ResultExercise

```
public class ResultsExercises implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_result_exercise")
private Integer idResultExercise;
@Column(name = "id_user")
private Integer idUser;
@Column(name = "id_course")
private Integer idCourse;
@Column(name = "id_lesson")
private Integer idLesson;
@Column(name = "id_activity")
private Integer idActivity;
@Column(name = "id_exercise")
private Integer idExercise;
@Column(name = "result_exercise")
private Boolean resultExercise;

public ResultsExercises() {
}

public ResultsExercises(Integer idResultExercise) {
    this.idResultExercise = idResultExercise;
}

public Integer getIdResultExercise() {
    return idResultExercise;
}

public void setIdResultExercise(Integer idResultExercise) {
    this.idResultExercise = idResultExercise;
}

public Integer getIdUser() {
    return idUser;
}

public void setIdUser(Integer idUser) {
    this.idUser = idUser;
}

public Integer getIdCourse() {
    return idCourse;
}

public void setIdCourse(Integer idCourse) {
    this.idCourse = idCourse;
}

public Integer getIdLesson() {
    return idLesson;
}

public void setIdLesson(Integer idLesson) {
    this.idLesson = idLesson;
}

public Integer getIdActivity() {
    return idActivity;
}

public void setIdActivity(Integer idActivity) {
    this.idActivity = idActivity;
}

public Integer getIdExercise() {
    return idExercise;
}

public void setIdExercise(Integer idExercise) {
    this.idExercise = idExercise;
}

public Boolean getResultExercise() {
    return resultExercise;
}

public void setResultExercise(Boolean resultExercise) {
    this.resultExercise = resultExercise;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idResultExercise != null ? idResultExercise.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof ResultsExercises)) {
        return false;
    }
    ResultsExercises other = (ResultsExercises) object;
    if ((this.idResultExercise == null && other.idResultExercise != null) || (this.idResultExercise != null && !this.idResultExercise.equals(other.idResultExercise))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "mx.com.nxtreallity.idiomas.entities.ResultsExercises[ idResultExercise=" + idResultExercise + " ]";
}
```

}

Clase SubmitResult

```
public class SubmitResult {
@JsonProperty
public boolean success;
@JsonProperty
public String message;
@JsonProperty
public HashMap<String, String> errors;
@JsonProperty
public HashMap<String,String > debug_formPacket;
@JsonProperty
public List items;
@JsonProperty
public String[][] itemsArray;
@JsonProperty
public HashMap<String,String > data;
@JsonProperty
public int results;  
@JsonProperty
public int rowCount;
@JsonProperty
public int errorCode;
//@JsonProperty
  public JSONObject jo ;

public SubmitResult() {
    this.message = "Operación realizada con éxito!";
    this.success = true;
    this.errors = new HashMap< >();
    this.debug_formPacket = new HashMap< >();
    this.data = new HashMap< >();
    this.items = new ArrayList();
    //this.jo = new JSONObject();

}
```

}

Espero me haya hecho entender, gracias por su tiempo...

Comment: Podrías poner el código de tu clase "ResutlsExercises"?

Comment: Claro, es la entidad de la tabla...

Comment: He actualizado  el post con el código de la entidad...

Answer (score 0):

La solución será crear una nueva clase con nombre ReturnResultExercises (o similiar) cuyos atributos tengan el nombre del JSON de salida que necesitas. Algo así:

```
public class ReturnResultExercises {
private Integer idResultExercise;
private Integer idUser;
private Integer idCourse;
private Integer idLesson;
private Integer idActivity;
private Integer idExercise;
private Boolean resultExercise;
}
```

Después, en tu clase "SubmitResult" tendrías un mapa de estos objetos en vez de un List de "ResultExercises".

```
@JsonProperty
public Map<String, ReturnResultExercises> items;
```

En el método de tu servicio, creas una instancia de ReturnResultExercises por cada ResultsExercises y construyes el mapa con ellas.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/list"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
SubmitResult listNewResultExercise(
        @RequestParam("idLesson") int idLesson,
        HttpServletRequest request
) throws IOException, Exception {

    SubmitResult result = new SubmitResult();

    ResultsExercisesJpaController jpaResultExe = new ResultsExercisesJpaController();
    try {
        List<ResultsExercises> foo = new ArrayList<ResultsExercises>();

    //Se ejecuta la consulta sql 
        foo = jpaResultExe.findLessonById(idLesson);

       Map<String, ReturnResultExercises> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

       for (ResultsExercises exercise : foo) {
          ReturnResultExercises rre = new ReturnResultExercises();
          rre.setIdResultExercise(exercise.getIdResultExercise);
         //[...] Other setters

         resultmap.put("exercisesIdActivity" + rre.getIdResultExercise, rre);
       }

        result.success = true;
        result.items = resultmap;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result.success = false;
        result.message = "Error: Al intentar retornar resultados " + ex.getMessage();

    }
    return result;
}
```

Podrías evitar el bucle implementando la transformación de List a Map usando los Streams de Java 8.

Es una buena practica encapsular tus datos de vuelta en una estructura diferente a la de la entidad de bbdd original. Así evitas exponer información sensible.

Comment: Funciona bien, pero cómo podría poner `                resultMap.put("exercisesIdActivity" + rre.getIdActivity(), rre); que sea un arreglo, porque solo se esta iterando una sola vez, y no esta metiendo todos los ejercicios correspondientes...
`